# Supporting multiple content types in a Spring-MVC controller

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, content-type

A Rails controller makes it very easy to support multiple content types.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :json => @obj }
  format.xml
  format.html
end
```

Beautiful. In one controller action I can easily respond to multiple content types with plenty of flexibility as to what I wish to render, be it a template, a serialized form of my object, etc.

Can I do something similar to this in Spring-MVC? What is the standard for supporting multiple content types in Spring? I've seen solutions involving view resolvers, but this looks difficult to manage, especially if I want to support JSON in addition to xhtml and xml.

Any suggestions are appreciated, but the simpler and more elegant solutions will be appreciated more ;)

**EDIT**

If I'm incorrect in asserting that a view resolver is difficult to manage, please feel free to correct me and provide an example. Preferably one that can return xml, xhtml, and JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Spring 3, you want to use the `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`.

It takes a list of media type and `ViewResolvers`.  From the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml"/>
      <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </map>
  </property>
  <property name="viewResolvers">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="content" class="com.springsource.samples.rest.SampleContentAtomView"/>
```

The Controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class BlogsController {

    @RequestMapping("/blogs")
    public String index(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("blog", new Blog("foobar"));
        return "blogs/index";
    }    
}
```

You'll also need to include the Jackson JSON jars.

Comment: Is is as easy and "beautiful" as Rails? No. But by Java standards, probably as good as we're going to get.

Comment: P.S. - I have only tested the HTML and JSON content types. I am working on atom, now.

Comment: @Todd: Thanks! It is a bit confusing though. If I'm returning the string "blogs/index", how do any of my views interact with my model? I was expecting it to return a ModelAndView object, to which we would pass the string "blogs/index", and then if the client requested JSON, Spring would just ignore this string and serialize the object through Jackson. Can you explain how your example is working?

Comment: @Samo, The blog model is set in the model, passed in (by reference) and is available to the view as 'blog'. The view "blogs/index" maps to "WEB-INF/jsp/blogs/index.jsp." And yes, when I add .json to my url, "/blogs.json" the view get ignored and prints `{"blog":{"name":"foobar"}}`

Comment: @Samo, you can use ModelAndView too.  I just tried it.

    @RequestMapping("/blogs")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        Blog blog = new Blog("foobar");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("blogs/index", "blog", blog);
        return model;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the working example controller, that renders JSON and HTML both based on request Header "Content-Type".

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class PersonService {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPersonByName(@RequestHeader("Content-Type") String contentMediaType,
            @PathVariable("userId") String userId,@RequestParam("anyParam") boolean isAscending) throws IOException {

        Person person = getPersonById(userId);
        if (isJSON(contentMediaType)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Person>(person, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity("Your HTML Goes Here", HttpStatus.OK);
        //Note: Above you could use any HTML builder framework, like HandleBar/Moustache/JSP/Plain HTML Template etc.
    }


    private static final boolean isJSON(String contentMediaType) {
        if ("application/json".equalsIgnoreCase(contentMediaType)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```