# Handling multiple content types in Spring MVC... which approach is preferred?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So, we are getting to the point in our Spring application where we need to decide how to handle views and content negotiation.  Previously, we've only supported one specific content type in our endpoints.

I'm going to throw our what I think our the three approaches.

**My question:** Which one is generally considered best practice/least amount of maintenance?  We are aiming for a solid convention to follow in our application, which can be broken where needed to provide flexibility if desired.

**First approach:**
Use ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.  This would involve a mapping defined in the servlet file... in the controller, each controller action would need to explicitly set the object in a map using some magic string.  The controller action would return a string which refers to a template name... sort of like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someMapping/source", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String foo(Model model)
{
    // more stuff here
    model.addAttribute(SOME_MODEL_KEY, new ArrayList<String>() { "hello world"});

    return "someDummyJsonString";
}
```

**Drawbacks:**
View resolvers seem a little unwieldy...  they have priorities, you need to override them often times, etc.  Also, I don't like the idea of the "magic strings" which are used to refer to template/View bean names.

**Second approach:**
I think this is new in Spring 3.0, but in `RequestMapping` you can match on headers... so you can match on the Accept header like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someMapping", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody SomeBar foo() 
{
  // call common controller code here
  return buildBar();
}

@RequestMapping(value="/someMapping", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=text/xml")
public String foo(Model model) 
{
  model.addAttribute("someModelName", this.buildBar()); 
  return "someTemplateNameProcessedByViewResolver";
}

SomeBar buildBar() 
{
   return new SomeBar();
}
```

**Drawbacks:**
Might not be flexible enough?  I'm not sure, but I think I really like the `headers` approach... I've seen other frameworks (RESTLet, Rails) use something similar.

**Third approach:**
The third approach involves making a custom `View` which will negotiate the content based on the `Accept` header, and throw the model through the appropriate method.  This content negotiating view would have to know a template, and load the template etc.:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someMapping", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=text/xml")
public View foo() 
{
  SomeBar bar = new SomeBar();
  ContentNegotiatingView view = new ContentNegotiatingView(bar, "templateName");

  return return view;
}
```

**Drawbacks:**
It seems like the view is doing too much in this case... the view would be looking at headers, and setting the response body itself.  It might need to set http statuses also.

So, sorry for the wall of text, let me know your thoughts on this.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone else just [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403643/supporting-multiple-content-types-in-a-spring-mvc-controller/). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403643/supporting-multiple-content-types-in-a-spring-mvc-controller/4404881#4404881).

Comment: So you would favor the view resolver approach over the header annotation approach?

Comment: To your point, the view resolver approach seems more flexible...and seems to the be the Spring recommended approach, based on my reading of the docs anyway.

Comment: Hm, maybe after a few years later we would probably all rather consider the annotation solution over the XML configuration file solution :)