# How to customize spring 3.0 json response?

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc

I am using spring 3.0 webservices. 
It produces a json response.

I want to generate jsonp response using same webservices.

Please suggest how to customize spring 3.0 webservices json response.

Comment: Can you please elaborate little bit more ??

Comment: Problem has been solved. I have added filter to the application which converts json response to jasonp response. I used jackson json converter to convert response to json.

Comment: Hi Ravi, as jquery ajax doesnt allow to make a crossdomain call for post request. To fix this i found that if we use jsonp it allow us to make crossdomain call. So i was trying to custimize spring json response to customized jsonp response where user can define callback funtion. Please suggest if you have any alternative approach to implement this. Right now i am using filter to modify json response at runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323625/how-to-support-jsonp-with-spring-mvc-and-multiple-response-types this might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to integrate Jackson in your project, which has tons of options for JSON serialization. Configuring Jackson is easy:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Once you get this working, you can use Jackson's excellent annotations on your Model objects to configure how they get printed in the JSON, or if they get ignored (@JSONIgnore).

If you want to go further, you can extend the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView class with your own, and go nuts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thaks Ivayo. It helped me alot.