# JavaScript submit button to return object response from spring MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, spring-mvc

Below code returns me a object response:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/NewLogin",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Token  getAllBooks( 
    Token token = new Token();
    token.setValue(encryptedMessage);
    return token;}
```

On clicking  the following button on jsp page :

```
 <input type="button" onClick="madeAjaxCall();" value="Ajax Submit">



<script type="text/javascript">

 function madeAjaxCall(){
     $.ajax({ 
         type: "post", 
         url: "http://localhost:8011/nLiveSite/livesearch/NewLogin", 
         cache: false,
         success: function(response){ 
             $('#result').html(""); 
             var obj = response; 
                console.log(obj);
             $('#result').html("Message:- " + obj );
             }, 
         error: function(){
             alert('Error while request..'); 
        } 
    }).responseText; 
} ;
</script>
```

Ajax Submit button is returning me content of jsp page as response. I need only object (i.e. token) as response on button click.

Comment: what is the response content-type and request content-type as seen in firebug?

Comment: it should be `url: "http://localhost:8011/NewLogin/",` ?

Comment: @DanielRobertus problem is not with URL hit as bying Writing alert in Success it is getting called and response shows full jsp page instead of response object.

Comment: @rps I am using  headers ="application/json" in controller class.

Comment: and java script has the following: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

Comment: @gjosh how if you try to use plain String and construct json by your self? `public @ResponseBody String  getAllBooks(){ return str;}`

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.....@url

```
url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/NewLogin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are expecting a HTTP POST request in your Rest API (besides the typos), however you are setting the Request type to "GET" in your AJAX request. Furthermore, the URL in your request doesn't match to "/NewLogin".

Comment: hi @schomax find the url  "~/nLiveSite/NewLogin/add.htm?_=1375182146256" Above example is with post but if I try with another get method still URL is getting appended with some value as shown here.

Comment: You can set both requests to type GET. If you want to append parameters it can be done with the option "data" within the ajax method, for example:  
    data: {value: 1}

Comment: Furthermore, you need to make sure that the service is hosted within the same domain as your web application. Otherwise you run into the "same origin policy" constraint, where you would need to use JSONP. That is further well explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11736771/2179109

Comment: And this is how to modify server and client for using JSONP, which worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10328288/2179109