# Internal forwarding from one controller method to another (Spring-MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring so not sure how i can do this.I have to handle 2 use case by using single controller method.

Method is already in place so i can not change the signature of it as it can break all other functionalists, here is the method signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit-address", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody JsonResponse editAddress()
```

`JsonResponse` is a custom object with following signature

```
private String status;
private Object result;
private String steps;
```

There is one more requirement where we need to validate this address from third part and based on the return results need to show pop-up.
I can easily show popu-up if the method signature was not a custom object, but now not sure how i can do this

is there a way to achieve any of the followwing

1. To send JSP content back to the view in place of JSON object from this method.
2. To internally forward control to another method in controller which can send back view to the UI

Comment: I think  what you really want is to use different views for different content types. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403643/supporting-multiple-content-types-in-a-spring-mvc-controller

Answer (score 0):

How about just composing this controller in another controller that you can control and delegating the call internally to this controller, this way:

```
@Controller
public class WrapperController{
    @Autowired JsonResponseController jsonResponseController;

    @RequestMapping("/custom_jspview")
    public String customRequestMapping(..., Model model){
        JsonResponse jsonResponse = this.jsonResponseController.editAddress();
        model.addAttribute("jsonresponse", "jsonResponse");
        return "myview";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/redirectView")
    public String redirectView(){
         return "redirect:/custom_jspview";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more descriptive, sorry not very sure about spring so need a bit more explanation :)

Comment: Yes, essentially what I am recommending is to not use JsonResponseController as a controller at all, but as another regular bean, then inject that bean into another custom controller that you have, and delegate calls from your custom controller to the JsonResponseController bean. This way you will have control over whether to serve out a view(a jsp, tiles, velocity view etc) or a json, as shown above.